# changing color of the JLABEL with a link

Tags: java, swing, colors, hyperlink, jlabel

how can i change the color of a JLABEL with a link in java?

```
    import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class XXX extends JFrame {
    XXX(){

        final JLabel lab1=new JLabel("Username:");
        final JTextField text1=new JTextField(20);
           lab1.setBounds(20,140,65,20);
           text1.setBounds(85,141,185,20);
           add(lab1);
           add(text1);
           lab1.setForeground(Color.white);

        final JLabel lab2=new JLabel("Password:");
        final JPasswordField text2=new JPasswordField(20);
           lab2.setBounds(20,165,65,20);
           text2.setBounds(85,166,185,20);
           add(lab2);
           add(text2);
           lab2.setForeground(Color.white);

        final JButton a=new JButton("Sign In");
        a.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //Code

            }
        });
        a.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
           a.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
           a.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
        {
            a.setEnabled(false);
            text1.setEditable(false);
            text2.setEditable(false);
          try {

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        });
           a.setBounds(85,192,80,20);
           add(a);

        final String strURL = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        final JLabel lab3 = new JLabel("<html><a href=\" " + strURL + "\">Register</a></html>");
        lab3.setBounds(170,192,52,20);
        add(lab3);
        lab3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
           lab3.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
           lab3.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
        {
           text2.setEditable(false);
          try {

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        });


        final JLabel map = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("XXXBG.png")));
        map.setBounds(0,0,300,250);
        add(map);





            setTitle("XXX");
            setSize(300,250);
            setResizable(false);
            setCursor(DEFAULT_CURSOR);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocation(8, 8);
            setLayout(null);
            toFront();
            setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    new XXX();
        }
}
```

as you can see, i cant change the foreground color of JLABEL lab3.
if posible, i want also to change color of border-like of the jframe.
anyone can help?

Comment: Ugh, get rid of those `setBounds(...)` calls and use layout managers. Towards you problem: if you want to be able to set the background color for a JLabel, you need to set its opaque property to `true` by calling `setOpaque(true)` on the JLabel. If that's not what you want to do, then please clarify the problem. And again get rid of those `setBounds(...)` calls.

Comment: i am beginner for this GUI in JAVA.. but i will try to use layout managers.

Comment: Very wise, you are, @MadProgrammer.  Yes, hmmm.

Comment: hey one more thing, i add setOpaque(true).. but it is only background who change color. i want to change the font color of the JLABEL..

Comment: i am using JCreator. and i cant see the changes.. in the lab3, still color blue and underlined.. and without the code for mouse event..it is not automatically changing the cursor.

Comment: why hovercraft want me to get rid of my setBounds()?..  what is the disadvantages of that?

Comment: @DieejayPeke: it makes your GUI rigid difficult to maintain or upgrade, and ugly on almost all systems except your own. In the long run it is much easier to use layout managers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Simple supply the `foreground` color you want to use...

```
lab3.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

You also don't need the mouse listener.  Simply using `lab3.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));` will change the mouse cursor automatically when the mouse is moved over the label for you...magically :D

**Updated**

```
public class TestLabel01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLabel01();
    }

    public TestLabel01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JLabel link = new JLabel("Linked in");
                link.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                link.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(link);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i think i have a missing line of code for the jlabel.. cause it is not changing(the cursor thing).

Comment: and also the jlabel color.. it is always color blue.. i want to change it to color white

Comment: @DieejayPeke: then change it to white -- no one is stopping you from doing this.

Comment: @DieejayPeke You 16 million colors to choice from, knock yourself out.  Also, updated with simple example, showing color and mouse

Comment: thanks guys.. only i need to do is.. <html><a href=\" " + strURL + "\"><font color=white>Register</a></html> add font color in html line..